# Array literal methods invocation and object literal methods invocation difference

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, I wonder why I can do this:

```
[].slice.apply([1,2,3], [0, 2]) // returns [1, 2]
```

Which is as far as I understand equivalent of this:

```
Array.prototype.slice.apply([1,2,3], [0, 2]); // returns [1, 2]
```

But I can't do this:

```
{}.hasOwnProperty.apply(a, ['a']);
```

Which would allow to not type this long line:

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.apply(a, ['a']); // returns true or false
```

Well, while I am at it, I also see that I can actually do all of these:

```
''.indexOf.apply('asdasd', ['s']); // returns 1
true.toString.apply(true); // returns // "true" as string
```

What the deal with {} ? :-) Why is it special?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is `hasOwnProperty('a')` a typo?

```
{}.hasOwnProperty.apply(a, ['a']);
```

But that doesn't *quite* work due to JavaScript interpreting `{}` as block delimiters. Just add parentheses:

```
({}).hasOwnProperty.apply(a, ['a']);
```

Check it:

```
> var a = {'a': 1}
  Object
> {}.hasOwnProperty.apply(a, ['a']);
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
> ({}).hasOwnProperty.apply(a, ['a']);
  true
```

Comment: thanks for noticing the typo – fixed! also, thanks for the answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

hasOwnProperty() returns true or false, not the actual property itself.

With your other examples, you are working with functions that are returned, not scalars or native objects, which is why you can call apply() on them.

Have you tried {}.hasOwnProperty.apply(......)?

Comment: Matt Ball has noticed  that {}.hasOwnProperty('a') was a typo, sorry. I did try `{}.hasOwnProperty.apply({a:'a'}, ['a']);` what I actually had to do is to wrap `{}` in parens, as answered above. thanks!

Comment: @gryzzly glad you found a solution. That's a tricky beast for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Brackets:

```
({}).hasOwnProperty.apply({k:9,aa:5}, ['a']); // false
({}).hasOwnProperty.apply({k:9,a:5}, ['a']); // true
```